# Is there a command to convert cm to bp?

Tags: conversion, lengths, dimensions

I want to convert a length in cm (centimeter) to bp (big point).
Is there a command to convert `cm` to `bp`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the `cm` in a register, which converts it into the internal `pt` format and then convert `pt` to `bp` using a 72/72.27 factor (`graphic/x` uses .99626).

You can use the eTeX macro `\dimexpr` for this. Then it is even expandable:

```
\def\converttobp#1{\the\dimexpr .99626\dimexpr #1\relax\relax}
```

This takes a `cm` or any other dimension and converts it to `bp` but return it without the `bp` unit attached. However the two conversions (cm->pt->bp) will add rounding errors.

You can avoid one of them by stripping the `cm` off and replacing it with `pt` to make TeX take in points instead, then convert it with the cm-to-bp factor of 28.3464567:

```
\makeatletter
\def\strip@cm#1cm{#1}
\def\cmtobp#1{\strip@pt\dimexpr 28.3464567\dimexpr\strip@cm #1 pt\relax\relax}
\makeatother
% Usage: \cmtobp{1cm} (returns value in bp without trailing unit)
```

If you want to use the `cm` value without unit and get a dimension with `bp` unit use:

```
\def\cmtobp#1{\strip@pt\dimexpr 28.3464567\dimexpr #1 pt\relax\relax bp}
```

Comment: there is a rounding error.

Comment: @xport: Yes, sure there is. TeX numeric accuracy isn't overwhelming. You can try a more accurate factor like  0.99626401 but I get the same result for e.g. 1cm. There should be reason why `graphics/x` uses it. If you want more accurate results I would convert it using an external script.

Comment: @Martin: how to add a trailing `bp` and remove `cm` when invoking `\cmtobp`. It means when I invoke `\cmtobp{2.54}`, I will get `72bp`.

Comment: @xport: I now updated my question to include this version.

Answer (score 3):

And if you need to "ceil" the result:

```
\makeatletter
\def\strip@cm#1cm{#1}
\def\cmtobp#1{\expandafter\@ceil
  \the\dimexpr 28.3464567\dimexpr\strip@cm #1 pt\relax\relax}

\begingroup\catcode`P=12 \catcode`T=12
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\@ceil#1.#2PT{\number\numexpr#1+0\ifnum#2>\z@ 1\fi\relax}}
\makeatother

\cmtobp{3cm} % -> 86
\cmtobp{2.54cm} % -> 72
\cmtobp{2.541cm} % -> 73
```

This uses the fact that `\the<dimen>` has always at least one decimal digit (possibly 0).

The following version has different input and output, as per request:

```
\makeatletter
\def\cmtobp#1{\expandafter\@ceil
  \the\dimexpr 28.3464567\dimexpr #1pt\relax\relax}

\begingroup\catcode`P=12 \catcode`T=12
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\@ceil#1.#2PT{\number\numexpr#1+0\ifnum#2>\z@ 1\fi\relax bp}}
\makeatother

\cmtobp{3}     % -> 86bp
\cmtobp{2.54}  % -> 72bp
\cmtobp{2.541} % -> 73bp
```