# How to clip a TeX box using low-level PS commands?

Tags: boxes, postscript, path-clipping, output-driver

I like to clip an arbitrary TeX box (`\hbox`) but without using larger graphic related packages like PGF/TikZ or PSTricks. This is intended to be used in packages which should not force the user to also load one of that packages.

Here I mean the same as the `clip` option (together with `viewport` or `trim`) of `\includegraphics` does: some outer material is not displayed any longer. I just want to apply this to a TeX box. I realize that this is output driver dependent. I found a `pdftex` solution already which uses PDF commands.
**I'm now looking for a DVI/PS solution, i.e. some `\special` instructions which clip a Tex box.** Any hints about other drivers are very welcome.

I need this for two of my packages `gincltex` and `adjustbox`, which both extend the features of `\includegraphics` to arbitrary TeX boxes.
What I do at the moment I simply use PGF for this: I place the content in a node and clip the picture accordantly. Because the content is boxed I can calculate the required size beforehand.

So basically I'm looking for the low level definition of a macro like:

```
\@clipbox{<llx>}{<lly>}{<urx>}{<ury>}{<boxnumber>}
```

which accepts a previously saved box and clips the four amounts from that box (`ll` = lower left, `ur` = upper right).

---

**For `pdftex`** I found the related code in `$TEXMF/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def` (driver file for `graphics`) which tells me trim the box first using normal TeX commands (i.e. to `\lower` and `\hskip` the lower left margin and to limit the box height (`\ht`) and width (`\wd`) dependent on the upper right corner. The depth `\dp` is there set to zero for images, but I have to handle that differently.). After that it uses the following low level macros to actually clip the box:

```
\pdfxform<boxnumber>
\pdfrefxform\pdflastxform
```

I imagine that for DVI-mode (`dvps` driver) I need a PostScript `\special` command to do the same. How would such a command look like? Any ideas about a `dvipdf` solution?

Comment: I already have a rough idea about `pdftex` (which seems to work with `\hbox`es anyway), so I would be happy to hear about Postscript solutions. The `\special{PSfile="#1" .. clip}` command I found in the `dvips.def` file doesn't help me much in this case.

Comment: Remember that XeTeX is unable to clip. :(

Comment: @egreg: Ok, so then clipping in PGF pictures doesn't work as well with XeTeX? It uses `dvipdfm`, doesn't it? (I'm totally XeTeX ignorant :-( )

Comment: @egreg: No, `\clip` with PGF works fine with XeLaTeX. I try to use the same lower level as PGF for as much output driver as possible. The rest will fall back to PGF.

Comment: I stand corrected; it can't clip included images, but TikZ pictures are correctly clipped. Maybe @Altermundus can help.

Comment: @egreg: Indeed. But it clips the same image when inside a TikZ picture! Maybe the driver is outdated.

Comment: @Martin: Did you solve this issue? In particular, I'm not clear what type of clipping you mean 'works' for XeTeX (as far as I know, there is no engine support for clipping there).

Comment: @Joseph: I found a TeX way to trim a box and a PDFTeX way to clip it rectangular. I didn't found any other support for DVI/PS mode or other compilers yet. Clipping works for XeTeX with PGF, but not with `graphicx`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I'm going to take a look at this with my 'LaTeX3 hat' on. If I succeed, I'll report back on both that and the 'back port' to normal syntax. Give me a few days :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks, but it should be mostly `\special` PostScript calls anyway, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both Herbert and Alexander have offered solutions for dvips. Here, I'm taking inspiration from those answers plus the more convenient approach available in pdfTeX, plus a modified version of the `pgf` method for XeTeX, and combining into a single approach. First, note that I'm assuming e-TeX and also using a somewhat 'LaTeX3-like' programming approach. I've also shared as much code as possible.

I'll use a single example but add comments along the way. First, as there are packages for the driver detections I'll load those.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf,ifxetex}
\makeatletter
```

The main internal macro takes five arguments: the box to modify, then four dimension expressions to be clipped off the left, bottom, right and top respectively. You could also set up a similar approach to take a final size. The idea here is that the baseline is respected if possible, so there is a bit of care needed with the vertical placement so that the content only moves down while there is some depth available.

```
\protected\long\def\box@clip#1#2#3#4#5%
  {%
    \ht#1\dimexpr\ht#1 - \dimexpr#5\relax\relax
    \ifdim\dp#1>\dimexpr#3\relax
      \dp#1\dimexpr\dp#1 - \dimexpr#3\relax\relax
    \else
      \setbox#1=\hbox
        {\lower\dimexpr\dimexpr#3\relax - \dp#1\relax\box#1}%
      \dp#1\z@
    \fi
    \wd#1\dimexpr\wd#1-\dimexpr#4\relax\relax
    \setbox#1=\hbox
      {%
        \hskip-\dimexpr#2\relax
        \box#1%
      }%
    \ifxetex
      \expandafter\box@clip@xdvipdfmx
    \else
      \ifpdf
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\box@clip@pdfmode
      \else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\box@clip@dvips
      \fi
    \fi
    #1%
  }
```

For each driver supported, there is an auxiliary. First, for dvips this is Herbert's method slightly altered (`pgf` makes things *very* complex):

```
\protected\long\def\box@clip@dvips#1%
  {%
    \setbox#1=\hbox
      {%
        \special
          {%
            ps:
              /mtrxc matrix currentmatrix def 
              currentpoint gsave
              translate
              Resolution 72 div VResolution 72 div scale
              0 -\to@bp{\dp#1} neg  \to@bp{\wd#1} \to@bp{\ht#1 + \dp#1} neg
              rectclip
              mtrxc setmatrix 
          }%
        \box#1%
        \special{ps: grestore }%
      }%
  }
```

As I said, pdfTeX makes life very easy :-)

```
\protected\long\def\box@clip@pdfmode#1%
  {%
    \pdfxform#1%
    \setbox#1=\hbox{\pdfrefxform\pdflastxform}%
  }
```

XeTeX is possibly the most complex one to tackle. The `pgf` approach is used, but here I've removed a lot of unnecessary transformations. After reading the dvipdfmx manual, it becomes clear that the best approach is as follows

```
\protected\long\def\box@clip@xdvipdfmx#1%
  {%
    \setbox#1=\hbox
      {%
```

The first special saves the current point and starts a new 'graphics level'. Using the `bcontent` operation saves the current location automatically.

```
        \special{pdf:bcontent }%
```

Draw a rectangle the size of the modified box: in `pgf` this is done using the lower-level `m`, `l` and `h` operations, but there is no gain in working that way. This will be located at 'current point' TeX-wise.

```
          \special
            {%
              pdf:literal direct 
                0 -\to@bp{\dp#1} \to@bp{\wd#1} \to@bp{\ht#1 + \dp#1} re 
            }%
```

The `W` operation specifies a clip, and `n` finalises the path without any output (it's a 'no-op').

```
          \special{pdf:literal direct W }%
          \special{pdf:literal direct n }%
```

Insert the box and tidy up.

```
                \box#1%
              \special{pdf:econtent }%
      }%
  }
```

A simple conversion taken from [Is there a command to convert cm to bp?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22701/is-there-a-command-to-convert-cm-to-bp)

```
\long\def\to@bp#1{\strip@pt\dimexpr0.99626\dimexpr#1\relax\relax}
```

Wrap everything up in a user macro and finish the code block

```
\protected\long\def\boxclip#1#2#3#4#5{\box@clip#1{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}
\makeatother

\newbox\testbox
```

Now for some testing.

```
\begin{document}
\setbox\testbox=\hbox{Some test text with (g)}
\boxclip{\testbox}{10 pt}{2pt}{5pt}{2 pt}

\noindent\box\testbox{}

\end{document}
```

(I'll be adding this to LaTeX3 now I know how it works!) If you want to see the effect of various parts of the XeTeX code, comment out the `W` line to turn off the clipping. You can also replace the `n` operations by `s` so that you get a box where the clipping path is.

---

In earlier versions of the answer, for XeTeX I used the `content q` operation to save the current location, but this requires a series of manipulations to get the clip path and the box insert to line up. Using the `bcontent` ... `econtent` pair is much clearer.

---

While using the XForm implementation for pdfTeX is convenient, in a case where code is to be shared between branches an alternative approach is possible. (The above could be viewed as an abuse of the XForm object system in any case).

```
\protected\long\def\box@clip@pdfmode#1%
  {%
    \setbox#1=\hbox
      {%
        \pdfsave
          \pdfliteral direct
            {%
              0 -\to@bp{\dp#1} \to@bp{\wd#1} \to@bp{\ht#1 + \dp#1} re W n
            }%
          \hbox to 0pt{\copy#1\hss}%
        \pdfrestore
        \hskip \wd#1
      }%
  }
```

The zero width box here is used to keep placement correct in the `\pdfsave`/`\pdfrestore` pair (which perform the same task as the `bcontent`/`econtent` pair for XeTeX but which should be places in the same output position.)

Comment: Thanks, that looks fantastic! I was working on XeTeX for the last two hours I was going to open a new question because I had problems with the PDF literals, I got the `q`, `m`, `l`, `W`, `n`, `Q` part but something seemed to be missing. Your answer comes also just at the right time!

Comment: @MartinScharrer What's crucial for XeTeX is the fact that the `content` literal inserts `q 0 0 0 <x> <y>` before the `<stuff>` and `Q` after, while `literal direct` does not. This is used to track the current location when needed.

Comment: @MartinScharrer It turned out that you only need two graphic layers: I've simplified the answer.

Comment: I worked this into the XeTeX driver for `adjustbox`: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/adjustbox/src/2a041fc594b7/adjxetex.def. Thanks again, I have to mention you in the source file. We should also think about creating XeTeX clipping support for `\includegraphics`, which is still missing.

Comment: Note that I changed your code a little. I got wrong results with the depth, so I changed the rectangle to a manual drawn one. I'm also using some existing internal macros from `adjustbox`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I'd got a "-" missing, and have fixed that.

Comment: I saw the missing `-` for the depth, but still got wrong results. The height was then not correct, for some reason. Maybe some baseline issue?

Answer (score 7):

%%%% only lines for some demo, delete the two later

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\makeatletter
\def\clipbox#1#2#3#4#5{% 
\leavevmode%   
  \special{ps: 
   /mtrxc matrix currentmatrix def 
   currentpoint  
   gsave translate 
   0 0 10 0 360 arc 0 0 1 gsave fill grestore setrgbcolor 0.5 setlinewidth  %%%%%%
   #1 #2 neg moveto #3 0 rlineto 0 #4 neg rlineto #3 neg 0 rlineto closepath  stroke %%%%
   newpath 
   #1 #2 neg #3 #4 neg 
   rectclip newpath  
   mtrxc setmatrix 
   }%
   #5% 
  \special{ps: grestore }%
}

\begin{document} 

\fontsize{60}{62} \selectfont Foo
\clipbox{30}{30}{400}{200}{Foo}
Foo

\end{document}
```

[image]

and here is a solution with dimensions and the correct scaling:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\makeatletter
\newlength\@templlx
\newlength\@templly
\newlength\@tempurx
\newlength\@tempury
\def\clipbox#1#2#3#4#5{% 
  \@templlx=#1%
  \@templly=#2%
  \@tempurx=#3%
  \@tempury=#4%
\leavevmode%   
  \special{ps: 
   /mtrxc matrix currentmatrix def 
   currentpoint  
   gsave translate Resolution 72 div VResolution 72 div scale
   newpath 
   \strip@pt\@templlx\space \strip@pt\@templly\space neg 
   \strip@pt\@tempurx\space \strip@pt\@tempury\space neg 
   rectclip newpath  
   mtrxc setmatrix 
   }%
   #5% 
  \special{ps: grestore }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\clipbox{0cm}{0cm}{1cm}{1cm}{\rule{4cm}{4cm}}%
\rule{1cm}{1cm}

\end{document}
```

The second square is unclipped  4cm x 4cm

[image]

Comment: Thanks Herbert, this looks very promising. I changed it a little for my application. However, I can't find out the proper scaling. The values should be in `bp`, don't they? I got an almost 10x to small size if I use my requested sizes when I convert them to `bp`. I actually already *trimmed* the content, so its official size is already set. I now like to use `\dp`, `\ht` and `\dp` to draw a clipping rectangle.

Comment: I'll have a look at weekend, currently I'm busy ...

Comment: ok, couldn't stop thinking about it ...  :-) Delete the two lines with %%%%%  tehy are only for demonstartion here

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the meantime I worked with your original code. I got it working for my application, but I still have a funny factor in it (~111.1111 = 1000/9). See https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/adjustbox/src/0feadff016c3/psclip.tex for the MWE. There seems to be a scale factor already active. I tried `initmatrix` which gave me a fresh matrix where I could scale directly, but most other text on the same page was then gone :-( I'm ok with how it is now, but would like to know if this will keep working or be influenced by some setting.

Comment: @Martin: use TeXs values for Resultion and VResolution. See edited answer

Comment: Thanks a lot Herbert. This answer helped me to understand the TeX-Postscript interaction better. In the end I went with Joseph's answer because it covers even more ground.

Answer (score 5):

Place

```
\special{ps: currentpoint /lly exch def /llx exch def}
```

and

```
\special{ps: currentpoint /ury exch def /urx exch def}
```

at the desired lower left and upper right corners of your box. 
This stores the Postscript coordinates into the `llx`, `lly`, `urx`, `ury` Postscript variables. These can later be used to define a clipping rectangle.

**EDIT:**

Below you find an example of a `\trimbox` command, which is similar to your requested `\@clipbox` in that it wants 4 TeX lengths and a box number. However, the four TeX lengths specify the amount measured from the box edges to be clipped.

Note that Glyphs are somewhat bigger than their box. See the first use of `\trimbox`.

The `q` has been put into the box to show that boxes with non-zero depth are correctly treated.

```
\def\trimbox#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \leavevmode%
  \special{ps: gsave}%
  \hbox to 0pt{\hskip#1\special{ps: currentpoint pop /llx exch def}\hss}%
  \hbox to 0pt{\hskip\wd#5\hskip-#3\special{ps: currentpoint pop /urx exch def}\hss}%
  \raise-\dp#5\hbox{\raise#2\hbox{\special{ps: currentpoint /lly exch def pop}}}%
  \raise\ht#5\hbox{\raise-#4\hbox{\special{ps: currentpoint /ury exch def pop}}}%
  \special{ps: llx lly urx llx sub ury lly sub rectclip}%
  \copy#5%
  \special{ps: grestore}%
}

\setbox0=\hbox{Foo q Bar}

x\trimbox{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{0}x\par
x\trimbox{2pt}{2pt}{2pt}{2pt}{0}x

\bye
```

Comment: I see. Good start, but how do I add the clipping rectangle?

Comment: You mentioned `\pdfxform` in your question. Do you want to implement a similar command to store the content of a TeX box into a PDF XObject for the dvips/ps2pdf driver?

Comment: I don't really care about the XObject. I only use it because it clips as a side-effect (I took this from the `pdftex.def` `graphics` driver). Here I like to clip in Postscript. I don't this `dvips` does PDF XObjects, does it?

Comment: Thanks, this looks now very good. I changed it a little for my application: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/adjustbox/src/211783d437dd/psclip2.tex. Note that `\@trimbox` already trims the box, i.e. reduces the official size, so that `\@clipbox` just has to remove the overlapping material. I like the fact that I don't have to do any conversation to PS lengths!