# Is there any specific reason to use LaTeX over XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex

Is there any situation in which it would be easier to do things in LaTeX rather than XeLaTeX?

Comment: Related questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/what-is-xetex-exactly-and-why-should-i-use-it contain some info.

Comment: It depends what you mean with LaTeX in this context. XeLaTeX is (a) LaTeX for once. I assume you mean either the "normal" DVI `latex` or `pdflatex` or both, don't you?

Comment: XeLaTeX doesn't fully support `microtype`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Process old documents.
- Use old tools which are not compatible with Unicode.
- For faster PSTricks.
- Need PostScript output only.
- Use some specials that XeTeX has not implemented. e.g. `patterns` and `fadings` library in `TikZ`. (Now latest SVN `TikZ` uses a new system layer to support patterns and fadings in XeTeX)

Comment: @Herbert: Martin wrote last month in c.t.t. that he has patched xetex.def to add clipping. The file is here (I haven't tested it yet) https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/adjustbox/src/efbfe90f3968/xetex/

Comment: @Herbert, Ulrike: The newest version is always under: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/adjustbox/src/tip/xetex/xetex.def. I already updated it a little since my c.t.t. post. Most of the technical implementation comes from Joseph Wright as part of [his answer to my clipping question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34421/2975).

Comment: @Ulrike: sorry, but that is not important for me if there might be a file elsewhere. Important is only that what comes with the current TeX distribution and there is still an old `xetex.def`

Comment: @Herbert: I think it is very good that Martin has started to do something about the "mess" in xetex.def. He needs people who test the new def, and for this he needs that the news about patch are spread around a bit.

Answer (score 6):

Xe(La)TeX exhibits the bug shown in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/using-minted-and-tabs/), so if you are doing something that requires writing tabs to an output file, it is more difficult to use XeTeX.

I myself encountered this bug when using the externalize functionality of `tikz`, which writes a Makefile containing tabs.  I find that the other features of XeTeX make up for having to hack around this bug, but if you aren't using those other features it is a pure annoyance.

Comment: Good. c.f. egreg's solution by passing `-8bit` option: [Tabs in output file written by xelatex and pdflatex are different](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14771/tabs-in-output-file-written-by-xelatex-and-pdflatex-are-different)