# What are the drawbacks of XeTeX/XeLaTeX vs standard LaTeX?

Tags: xetex, typography, tex-general

I'm planning to switch back to \LaTeX{}, but I would like to be able to use any `.ttf` font that I need.

Back in the time I used to format any document with LaTeX I was comfortable with the terribly restricted list of available fonts (after I converted a couple, I learnt to accept the limitation). I don't think I can cope with that limitation again, as I will be needing to format corporate documents that sometimes use a given font.

And I don't want to go through the dantesque process of converting every font I need, as it certainly was a painly process that I would not like to repeat.

I've found that XeTeX (or XeLaTeX, are they the same?) enable the use of true type fonts painlessly, and in [this same site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226/installing-ttf-fonts-in-latex) some disadvantages of this engine are glimpsed, though not very detailed.

Hence my question, what are the drawbacks/limitations I would be facing if I decide to take the XeTeX route?

Comment: You can use only some of the features of microtype.

Comment: Are you familiar yet with [the LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/)? It might be that you won't need XeLaTeX at all.

Comment: we have had this question before and has extensive answers. please seaech the site for it.

Comment: Related/Possibly Duplicate of [What is XeTeX exactly and why should I use it?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3393/15717) or [Is there any specific reason to use LaTeX over XeLaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37257/15717)

Comment: related [Differences between LuaTeX, ConTeXt and XeTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex)

Comment: Oops, I did a couple of searches, but didnt yield to these two topics. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: I didnt know that font catalogue, @SergeStroobandt The fonts I need aren't there, but it is good to know its existence :)