# pdfcrop and --bbox command line option

Tags: pdftex, pdfcrop

This tool that's distributed with texlive has no actual documentation for the `bbox` parameter. It just says that

```
--bbox "<left> <bottom> <right> <top>"
```

What units do these number follow? Say I have a letter sized paper, what will be the intervals on which these numbers are defined? Also is the right coordinate computed from the left or right margin? Same with top.

Answer (score 6):

These *coordinates* are referenced as `bp` (or `b`ig `p`oints), which is different from TeX's `pt`. More specifically, `1in` is equivalent to `72bp` or `72.27pt`.

A letter-sized paper (`8.5in` x `11in`) consists of `612bp` x `792bp`, typically with coordinates gives as `(0,0)` and `(612,792)`. Since these are coordinates, they are not calculated from one another. That is, coordinates of the form `(100,100)` and `(712,892)` would still represent a letter-sized paper, while `(100,100)` and `(612,792)` represents a sheet of paper that has dimensions `7.11in` x `9.61in`.

Conversions between units is available, as an example, from [Is there a command to convert `cm` to `bp`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22701/5764)

Comment: Wikipdia says 1 point = 1/72 inch, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29. What is the difference and relation between point and big point? Does "pt" in TeX not mean "point" in Wikipedia?

Comment: @Tim: Yes, there is a difference. Wikipedia's *point* refers to a *big point* in TeX. TeX's *point* is a little smaller. See [Why does a TeX point differ from a Desktop Publishing point?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200934/5764)