# Why does a TeX point differ from a Desktop Publishing point?

Tags: tex-core, typography, unit-of-measure

From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200885) to [Why does PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX generates 11.955 font size for 12pt documentclass option?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200882/62411), I found out that PDF and `TeX` have different ideas about the size of the point (`pt`). A `TeX` point is 1/72.27 inch, where Desktop Publishing Point (DPP), or a Big Point (BP) is 1/72 of an inch.

What is the historical and/or technical reason for this difference?

Comment: Palindromes were preferred. Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @cfr: I'm not a native speaker, so I don't quite get the meaning of "Palindromes were preferred". The guide states that we should insert the link directly, so I have inserted the question link. Hope this is acceptable?

Comment: This question: [Globally redefining 1 pt to 1/72 in (PostScript point) and other similar changes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21758) has most of the answer in the question. The TeX point is derived from the the [Traditional American Point System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29#Traditional_American_point_system).

Comment: @Krumia It was a bit of friendly sarcasm—`72.27` is a [palindrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) :) Also, the rest of @cfr's comment is a 'boilerplate' welcome—something we give *all* new users in some variation.

Comment: Oh! I did not get _that_. All is well then. :)

Comment: Knuth decided to use the traditional unit. Adobe, but perhaps they weren't the first, preferred an arbitrary rounding to 72 points per inch. Which is as stupid as imposing that there are 25 millimeters per inch just to help computations: should the inch shrink or the millimeter stretch? `;-)`

Comment: @Krumia As Sean Allred said. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @egreg actually, the size of an inch changed, and there were several sizes of foot around. Knuth grew up with traditional American typesetters. I’ve just recherched point sizes and history, because I have found conflicting information about the Teχ point. It is in fact 1/72.27 of the modern (25.4 mm) inch, or 800/803 of the PostScript point (1/72 inch). The modern inch was already in force when the PostScript point was defined, and has taken over computing (all except Teχ).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The history about the pica pint is quite interesting (at least for me). And it has to do with the way we measure types.

### In the beginning

From the early days of the emergence of the printing press, and the mythical Gutenberg and for a long time, each printer, each workshop had its own way of measuring the types used. Its own scale.

This scale was arbitrary and used certain *grades* or *reference magnitudes* that were quite quaint and with curious names, at least in the Spanish typographic tradition. In the English one I don't know, but the idea should not differ much.

### Towards a standard measure

It was not until the eighteenth century when the matter began to be normalized. At the end of the first half of this century, a French printer named Pierre Simon Fournier (the younger) tried to normalize that mess by creating a unit of typographic measure: the point. What Fournier did was take the smallest *grade* and he divided it into six parts, so the sixth part was *the point* and eleven points formed a *cicero*.

Almost twenty years later, François-Ambroise Didot perfected the defining point system from a French measure of length called *pied-du-Roi*, where 12 points (12 was a common number for dividing things before the metric system) formed a *cicero* related now with the ancient French inch. Notice that curiously it is France that began to normalize and look for a more orderly system of rational measurement, which gave rise to the metric system, SI base.

And so the Didot point, which was the unit of typographic measure most popular in Europe until the second half of the twentieth century, except in England and its colonies, was established.

In the Anglo-Saxon world, the cicero had its counterpart, a unit of similar length called the *pica*, which in turn also divides into 12 parts called *points*. So far we have two types of points: pica points and Didot points. The Didot points were defined as the 1/144 part of the old French inch, meanwhile the pica point measures 1/72.27 of an inch. I honestly do not know to what that extra 0.27 is due, but in traditional English typographic practice that is the value that it has been for centuries.

### Then came Knuth and there was light

Then the (western) world was divided into two for a long time; measurement systems were not compatible. It is in this part of the story when **Donald Ervin Knuth** who is, as we all know here (I think), among many other things, the author of TeX, which in turn is the basis of LaTeX, ConTeXt, etc. Knuth was born in Milwaukee, Wisconsin, where his father owned a small printing business where Knuth, since childhood, was familiar with the technique of composition with types, which years later will abstract to create TeX. In those years the traditional pica and pica point ​​were not rounded.

### Adobe conquers the world

In the second half of the twentieth century appeared computers, which in the 80s began to become popular and to enter into virtually all human activity, including typography. The 80s were the times of typographical democratization. They were also the days in which Adobe and *PostScript* emerged, and quickly spread throughout the world. Then came the war of the Desktop Publishing systems and everything else.

It was then, when from Adobe came the idea of ​​simplifying the point, rounding it to 1/72, whereby a smallest point was obtained but it was fully compatible with the English inch. Opposition to this practical idea must have been very small, let alone considering Adobe's influence is such that it has been the market leader ever since. And that is the cause of the discrepancy in measurements between the TeX point and that used by Adobe products and software manufacturers that support the standard imposed by Adobe.

As you can see in [egreg’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200954), *The TeXbook* is an earlier piece than the domination of Adobe and its rounded pica which is called also the *PostScript pica*. And that's why TeX works with traditional pica points. Because it was created by a man born inside that typographic tradition (and not the European) and it was a few years before the tradition changed. Currently the PostScript pica is used by almost everyone (even unknowingly), so that Didot points and other measurement systems are practically extinct.

---

Nevertheless TeX is able to work with all the units mentioned in this story.

> **Absolute units:**
>
> dd *Didot point:* (1157 dd = 1238 pt)
>
> cc *cicero:* (1cc = 12 dd)
>
> pt *Traditional pica point* (and the default LaTeX unit)
>
> pc *Pica:* (1 pc = 12 pt)
>
> cm *centimetre:* (2.54 cm = 1 in)
>
> mm *millimetre:* (10 mm = 1 cm)
>
> in *inch:* (1 in = 72.27 pt)
>
> bp *big point or rounded point or PostScript point:* (72 bp = 1 in)
>
> sp *scaled point:* (65536 sp = 1 pt) The smallest length unit in `TeX`.
>
> **Relative units:**
>
> em *the `em` quad, a space that is one `M` letter wide*
>
> ex *the height of an `x` or the lower case letters.*

These are the units that TeX supports that can be used in any document. More than what a Desktop Publishing System can withstand. As I remember, InDesign, e.g., can work with centimetres, millimetres, inches, picas and points, both PostScript and traditional, but I think not with ciceros or Didot points.

Comment: @Aradnix -- nice summary.  i've given it a "tugboat" level editorial reading, and tidied up the english (and a few factual details) accordingly.  hope you don't mind.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Of course not, on the contrary, I am honored by this, but at the time I feel ashamed for my bad English.

Comment: @Aradnix -- please don't be ashamed of your command of english.  unless you learn a language as a child by talking to native speakers, it's a tough job mastering the nuances.  my command of several languages other than english is good enough to read simple text, get a good meal in a restaurant, and say "thank you", but i will never achieve native fluency.  (i am grateful that english is so well established in so many places that communication is actually possible.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for your words, I know it is a hard work, but if I could, I would like to eventually express myself almost as native, in English and some other of the languages ​​I know. For now, English is the _lingua franca_ of our times and I also enjoy to make myself understood with people around the world in English.

Comment: “[…] it was created by a man born inside that typographic tradition (and not the European) […]” → this seems incorrect to me, as Adobe is an American company that invented (or at least spread) PostScript, so you can't speak of a European tradition.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel What I mean is that Donald Knuth was 
within the English or Anglo-Saxon typographical tradition based in the pica instad of the Didot point used mostly in Europe. Am I wrong with that?

Comment: Ah, you mean it *that way*. But England is part of Europe, too. Moreover, it's merely time that divides the typographic tradition in which Knuth was born and the one Adobe established, not space, as your remark between parentheses suggests. I would omit that part completely.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I know about people in England who consider Europe (or the Continent) as something apart. Anyway, I'm not denying membership in the strict sense of England to the European continent, I am referring to the difference in typographic traditions in the _Anglo-Saxon_ world and the rest of Europe influenced by France. Much of the world adopted one or another by the influence of these European countries had over their colonies and other territories. Thus in my country (Mexico) was common to use the pica, meanwhile in Argentina for example, was more common the use of cicero.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I don't understand that difference in space you mention, in terms of time between childhood Knuth and the popularization of the Adobe products, we are agree.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not fully clear, as I'm not a native English speaker, too, but I meant that your remark between parentheses might suggest that Adobe and the PostScript point is a European tradition, but you can also read it as you probably meant it: Knuth was born in the tradition of the pica point. I now see another issue with your text: perhaps you should omit the remark “(and the default LaTeX unit)”, as there is no default unit (at least not in TeX, leaving out the unit will cause an error).

Comment: Ok, let me review the full text for avoid those misunderstandings. Thanks for the remarks.

Comment: I’ve just recherched point sizes and history, because I have found conflicting information about the Teχ point. It is in fact 1/72.27 of the modern (25.4 mm) inch, or 800/803 of the PostScript point (1/72 inch). This is because the size of the inch/foot changed, and (as you pointed out) there were several kinds of foot around (e.g. survey, printer’s, etc). The printer’s foot was 249⁄250 of the then-normal foot, but only after the international inch/foot was defined, we get the current 1/72.27 ratio.

Comment: @mirabilos I knew about the existence about different measures of inches, feet, etc. Bit I never thought about the actual size of the foot employed by printers.

Answer (score 28):

The size of a printer's point was fixed at the Fifteenth Meeting of the Type Founders Association of the United States in 1866 as 0.013837 in (see this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)).

Quoting from the TeXbook (chapter 10):

> The units have been defined here so that precise conversion to sp
>   is efficient on a wide variety of machines. In order to achieve this,
>   TeX's “pt” has been made slightly larger than the official printer’s
>   point, which was defined to equal exactly 0.013837 in by the American
>   Typefounders Association in 1886 [cf. National Bureau of Standards
>   Circular 570 (1956)]. In fact, one classical point is exactly
>   0.99999999 pt, so the “error” is essentially one part in 10<sup>8</sup>.
>   This is more than two orders of magnitude less than the amount by which
>   the inch itself changed during 1959, when it shrank to 2.54 cm from
>   its former value of (1/0.3937) cm; so there is no point in worrying
>   about the difference. The new definition 72.27 pt = 1 in is not only
>   better for calculation, it is also easier to remember.

At the end of the 1980's, desktop publishing systems began to spread and they used the proposal by the creators of Adobe PostScript, who arbitrarily decided that one point should be 1/72 of an inch. This was probably supposed to help computations, but clearly shows a bias towards a measurement system that's *almost only* used in the United States, while the rest of the world has been with the SI system for several decades. I find this decision similar to decreeing that, for helping conversions in desktop publishing, the millimeter should be redefined so that 25 mm = 1 in, which is clearly absurd.

The PostScript point is 0.3% longer than a printer's point: 72 printer's point are thus 25.3 millimeters rather than 25.4. If you look at the textwidth of `article` at 10pt, which is 345 printer's points, we get 121.25 millimeters, while 345 PostScript points are 121.71 millimeters. I wouldn't worry about the difference.

Comment: *"...desktop publishing systems began to spread and they used the proposal by the creators of Adobe PostScript, who arbitrarily decided that one point should be 1/72 of an inch."* Citation?

Comment: Saying the rounding is analogous to redefining the millimeter is really not very apt. Adobe took a completely arbitrary length which bore no connection to any other length or system of measurement (except via tradition) and redefined it to fit with the Imperial system, which given the size of the US market, not to mention the various Commonwealth countries in which despite metrification, Imperial units are still in common use as well as SI units, isn't really that bad an idea. Preserving the old point for the sake of tradition is just that: for the sake of tradition.

Comment: Whether the Postscript point should have been normalized to some metric measure is a different question, and likely didn't even occur to Adobe.

Comment: @AlanMunn The real reason why Adobe normalized the point is that they used a ***much*** larger base unit than TeX's scaled point and at the beginning of PostScript, almost everything was expressed as integer multiple of their point.

Comment: Actually, a point was 1/72 inch for both Teχ and PostScript, it’s just that the inch/foot they used as base differed, see the [Wikipedia article on the typographic point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29#American_points) for details.

Comment: @mirabilos Sorry, no. The inch was slightly changed in 1959, which had a small consequence on the printer point (this is discussed in the TeXbook), well before TeX and Postscript were born. Knuth decided to use the printer's point (72.27pt = 1in), while Warnock decided to use a different unit (also called point by him), 1/72 of an inch, in 1976 when he designed the first version of Postscript. This is why Knuth also defined the “big point” unit for use in TeX.

Comment: Yes, but the printers' point was also defined as 1/72th of an inch, just a different inch, *originally*.

Comment: @mirabilos With a foot quite different from the layman's. American units were (and are) a mess.

Comment: To note: based on the definitions given in the TeXbook, the lengths of the NBS printer's point and the TeX point can't be distinguished by TeX (with a difference of only `0.130sp` or 0.700 nanometers).