# Why is the font bigger than normal?

Tags: fontsize

When I compile the pdf file, even though I have the font set to 12pt it is bigger. I leave here my full preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\addto\captionscatalan{\renewcommand*{\bibname}{Fonts d'informaci\'o}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\parskip=2mm
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\subsection{Hibridació d'orbitals}
\subsubsection{Orbitals híbrids sp$^3$}
La configuració electrònica del carboni, en el seu estat fonamental\footnote{Estat d'energia més baix possible d'un sistema quàntic, com per exemple d'un àtom o d'un electró.}, és 1s$^2$ 2s$^2$ 2p$_x^{\ 1}$ 2p$_y^{\ 1}$. 
L'àtom pot utilitzar els dos electrons dels orbitals p per formar dos enllaços covalents. Per exemple, si realitza dos enllaços amb dos àtoms d'hidrogen, s'obté una molècula de metilè, una molècula molt inestable perquè el carboni només conté sis electrons a la seva capa de valència. 

El carboni també pot enllaçar amb quatre àtoms a través de l'excitació\footnote{Transferència d'un electró a un estat més energètic, mitjançant la recepció d'energia d'un fotó o d'un altre electró excitat.} d'un electró de l'orbital 2s cap a l'orbital 2p que estava buit. Així s'obté aquesta configuració electrònica: 1s$^2$ 2s$^1$ 2p$_x^{\ 1}$ 2p$_y^{\ 1}$ 2p$_z^{\ 1}$, que posseeix quatre electrons desaparellats que poden formar enllaços covalents. La formació de quatre enllaços és afavorida des del punt de vista energètic, ja que l'energia alliberada per la formació de quatre enllaços enlloc de dos és més elevada que l'energia necessària per obtenir l'estat excitat de l'electró i a més el carboni enllaçat a quatre àtoms és estable estructuralment\footnote{Estructura d'octet, amb vuit electrons a la capa de valència, és a dir, la capa plena.}.

Totes les molècules tendeixen a assolir l'estat d'energia més baix i, en el cas de molècules formades pel carboni enllaçat de manera covalent a quatre radicals, aquest s'obté si els quatre enllaços són equivalents, és a dir, si estan formats pel mateix tipus d'orbital. Aquests quatre orbitals equivalents s'obtenen mitjançant la hibridació de l'orbital 2s i els orbitals 2p, en orbitals híbrids sp$^3$. Els orbitals híbrids són els orbitals que s'obtenen quan es combinen diferents tipus d'orbitals per donar lloc a orbitals nous, amb nivells d'energia i formes noves.
\end{document}
```

The document doesn't have anything that could change the font, it's just text, with some mathematical formulas and graphics.

I use MikTeX, TeXmaker and pdfLaTeX. Is this something to configure in the interface? My friend uses the same and she has it correctly: the font displays as 12pt (comparing it with other text editors).

This is what my log says about fonts:

```
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbsy10.pfb>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti12.pfb>
```

[image: This is how I get the pdf file.]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. Why do you think the font is larger than 12pt? (Rather than, say, your friend's being smaller, for example.)

Comment: it's not possible to say anything given no information. Please make the document a complete document that shows the problem

Comment: so your log shows you have 12pt fonts (apart from some 10pt fonts in math and a 17pt font in your heading), that log doesn't show if the fonts are scaled but latex doesn't scale cm fonts so much as it is available in different design sizes.

Comment: If I add `\showthe\font` before `\end{document}`, I get `\OT1/cmr/m/n/12` which means a 12pt font as requested. You should add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but it's another matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document as posted just uses 12 (TeX) point fonts, the log shows at the end:

```
</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt12.pfb>
```

The revised example also uses 12pt body font:

[image]

Comment: @Nuria what makes you think the fonts are larger than 12pt?

Comment: Subsubsection titles are smaller than normal text, and there are about 70 characters per line.

Comment: the point of an example is to demonstrate the problem, fix your example not to include an image (since it just generates an error for those of us without that image) and include a subsubsection

Comment: I think @Nuria is measuring with [PostScript points](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200934/why-does-a-tex-point-differ-from-a-desktop-publishing-point/200968#200968) instead of the traditional Pica points that `TeX` uses as David says.

Comment: @Aradnix that's why I asked why the OP thought the fonts were big, answer didn't indicate measurement....

Comment: @Nuria I updated answer with an image

Comment: I updated the post with an image of my pdf file.

Comment: @Nuria Notice also that the _pont size_ you measured as 12 pt includes also the [shoulders](http://www.letterpress.dwolske.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/anatomy-of-printing-type.jpg), is not only the Uppercase height as you can measure with a typometer (BTW the IEC (Institut de Estudis Catalans) has a very nice one).

Comment: Even if the shoulders are included, that should make the font smaller, not bigger. Also, the subsubsection and subsection titles should be bigger than normal text.

Comment: @Nuria they are bigger than the body text, see the image I posted

Comment: But in my file (see the image) they are smaller. I think the code is not the problem, but the program. Can it be?

Comment: @Nuria is that image made from the file you posted here (as if you copied and pasted it back from the website) if so something is very wrong with your setup: it should look like the image I posted which is made from an unedited copy of your text

Comment: @Nuria I don't think your image is from your example as the first footnote starts at 7 ?

Comment: It is from the full document, i posted only a part of it. The problem is not there, since I've been having this problem since I started the document but didn't have time to solve it.

Comment: @Nuria it is not helpful to us (so we can not help you) if you post an example that does not have the problem. if the example is fine but your full document is wrong, all we can say is some code you have not shown has an error in it.

Comment: Since you say the problem is in the code, I went through it, and the font was bigger because there was a \begin{Large} \end{Large} environment, but it was closed, so I don't know what caused it. But it's solved now.

Comment: @Nuria There is no such environment that I know of. There is a font switch command `\Large` which makes the font larger until something changes the size again. `\normalsize` would return to the default size selected for the document.

Comment: @cfr any command can be used as an environment (it's not always a good idea but it's part of the latex design that you can do it)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. (Damn! I always forget that.)