# Line Width not accurate in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, luatex

I'll try to demonstrate my issue with a simple example.

Suppose I compile the following file (I used LuaLaTeX, TeX Live 2015)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xlabel=$x$,
      ylabel=$y$
    ]
    \addplot[line width=0.8pt]{x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I examine the produced pdf file with a vector graphic program (e.g. Adobe Illustrator), I note that the line width of the graph is 0.797pt instead of the requested 0.8pt.

Although I know that the error is negligible for all practical purposes, it would be interesting to know its cause.

Comment: 1 TeX point (`pt` in TeX) = 0.99628 big (PostScript/Adobe) point (`bp` in TeX). See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8337/21344

Comment: Thanks @PaulGessler ! Adding this interesting link that I've found about this also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200934/why-does-a-tex-point-differ-from-a-desktop-publishing-point