# Point to inch conversion different

Tags: units, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a diagram with matplotlib and embed it in latex. I want the diagram to have the full textwidth so I printed the textwidth in points to my document with `\the\textwidth`. The value I've got is `418.25555pt`. However when I convert this value to inches with google for instance I get: `5.80910486111`. This, however, is based on the assumption that one inch equals 72 pt. This is different from the information given here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths

It says 1 inch equals 72.27 pt. I wrote a helper function in python to convert points to inches:

```
import scipy.constants as sc

def figsize(scale, textwidthInPt):
    textwidthInInch = textwidthInPt * sc.pt / sc.inch  #1
    figWidthInInch = textwidthInInch * scale
    figHeightInInch = figWidthInInch / sc.golden_ratio
    return [figWidthInInch, figHeightInInch]
```

The line marked with `#1` shows the conversion to inch. The constants from scipy are also based on the `1 in = 72 pt` equality.

All my plots are slightly to wide and cause an overfull hbox warning.

Why is LaTeX different in this case?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). that illustrates your problem with the plots. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: LaTeX has two different "point" units:  big points `bp`, and traditional printer's points `pt`, defined as `72.27 pt = 72 bp = 1in`.

Comment: From my own experience, you should use `tight_layout()` on your figures in matplotlib for the inclusion in LaTeX (just a tip).

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200934/why-does-a-tex-point-differ-from-a-desktop-publishing-point