# bp (PostScript point) pica?

Tags: dimensions, unit-of-measure

A few months ago I noticed while inspecting some of my LaTeX-generated PDFs that the font sizes used were not what I had specified. I went to check the source file, but all my font sizes were just how I wanted them to be.

Recently I came across the `bp`, and how what TeX defines as a point does not match up with the standard. So I did a quick search-and-replace across the source file – everything went perfectly! I now had the font sizes I wanted.

However, I soon realised that the pica is still based on TeX’s point, so I’m wondering if I could define a new measurement in LaTeX called a `bpc`, or something of the kind, that is equal to `12bp`.

Is this possible? Thanks for the help!

Comment: There is not really a standard defining the [point (typography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography))....

Comment: @PaulGaborit I meant the standard among computers and software. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Long ago (a few years actually) someone else asked a similar question where I elaborated on a fairly detailed answer that might be helpful to you, [here it is](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200934/why-does-a-tex-point-differ-from-a-desktop-publishing-point/200968#200968)

Comment: @Aradnix thanks for your detailed answer! Although it is very interesting, and adds more information to the subject of the different measurements used throughout typography, it would be very helpful if you could clarify how to define a new measurement in LaTeX.

Comment: @AramisRazzaghipourwhy do you need to define a new measurement? We have enough. Actually I don't know how to answer your question, I have to ask about it but I guess it has to do with TeX directly.

Comment: @Aradnix I would prefer to define a new measurement because I would like picas to be consistent with the PostScript points that I use. It is inconvenient to have to write multiples of twelve out in full so that I can get the right measurement instead of simply using a variant of `pc`.

Comment: @AramisRazzaghipour In fact, the standard is what TeX handles, bp was not when TeX was created and then LaTeX and ConTeXt, however, Adobe has been who has popularized that measure unit. I haven't found the answer to your question yet, unfortunately, I just wanted to point out this clarification for what I just reread.

Comment: @AramisRazzaghipour Take a look at this [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/setting-a-document-in-ms-word-12pt-12bp), it may be useful for you.