# Rotate landscape for single page and also the pagenumber?

Tags: pdftex, rotating, landscape

I found [here on tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19021/74646) an excellent & beautiful portrait-but-1-page-landscape-table snippet (see below).

This is exactly what I need, however I want a pagenumber, but when I comment out thispagestyle{empty}, then the **pagenumber itself is *not* rotated.** So that is still portrait.

How to get the footer/header also rotated? The rest need to stay the same (well functionally, so only impact a single page with table, \afterpage, PDF rendering, etc).

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum % Text before
\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
  %  \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
        \centering % Center table
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            A & B & C & D \\
        \end{tabular}
        \captionof{table}{Table caption}% Add 'table' caption
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage% Flush page
}
\lipsum % Text after
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I use my `\atxy{x-loc}{y-loc}{text}` technique from [What are the ways to position things absolutely on the page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169808/what-are-the-ways-to-position-things-absolutely-on-the-page/169831#169831) to place something at an arbitrary position on the page.  The location I select is `{\dimexpr\paperwidth-1in}{.5\paperheight}` which is horizontally centered relative to the new orientation, 1in from the new bottom of the page.  What I typeset there is `{\rotatebox[origin=center]{90}{\thepage}}`.  Of course, I allow `\thispagestyle{empty}` so that this new page number is in lieu of the natural LaTeX page number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everypage,graphicx}
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum % Text before
\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
    \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
    \atxy{\dimexpr\paperwidth-1in}{.5\paperheight}{\rotatebox[origin=center]{90}{\thepage}}
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
        \centering % Center table
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            A & B & C & D \\
        \end{tabular}
        \captionof{table}{Table caption}% Add 'table' caption
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage% Flush page
}
\lipsum % Text after
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: STEVEN Thank you HOWEVER. This POC is working, but not correctly in my setup.  I can place text with fixed cm, but with your parameters it does not work. QUESTION: How can output "\dimexpr\paperwidth-1in" and then converted in centimeter? I tried adding this as text but then I get the error " ! You can't use `\dimexpr' in restricted horizontal mode."

Comment: @jos I am not sure I fully understand the problem.  The macro `\dimexpr` says to convert what follows into a dimensional quantity, thus allowing primitive length additions/subtractions in a place that otherwise expects a single length spec.  The process is terminated by an unexpandable `\relax` or, in this case, a `}`.  You should be able to say, for example, `\dimexpr\paperwidth-1cm\relax` if you wanted to specify the offset from the bottom as a metric centimeter.  Given a particular document style, I see nothing wrong with replacing `\dimexpr\paperwidth-1in` with a fixed length: `xx cm`.

Comment: @jos To print it out, `\the\dimexpr...`, but it will be in points.  There are questions on this site for how to convert to other length units.

Comment: @jos Something like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22701/is-there-a-command-to-convert-cm-to-bp, but with a different conversion factor.

Comment: your solution is not 100% rock solid yet as it does not always work if you change margins via newgeometry. Follow up question as "answer" in this thread.

Comment: @jos Follow ups should typically be asked as a new question, with a web link back to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The beautiful solution of Steven is not working rock solid yet. **The pagenumber is falling off the page in a similar MWE (see below).**

First question: why can't the PageTopMargin/PageleftMargin offsets be taken as current page margins? Why are they hardcoded?

Assume I have A4 with default margins 3.5 cm. For the landscape table I move to 1cm margins. If I follow Stevens approach, the following snippet would print the pagenumber on the right location. *However it is not visible (outside page).*

I can get the example below visible by changing to:

```
\def\PageLeftMargin{3cm}
```

Which is a bit strange, but then it is still not nicely aligned horizontally (driven by PageTopMargin). So I can get this working by playing around with the constants, however I am curious about a real solution.

**MWE, Page Number falling off the page, what is not expected based on Steven's example.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=35mm,bottom=35mm,left=35mm,right=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{everypage,graphicx}
\def\PageTopMargin{1cm}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1cm}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{capt-of}% or use the larger `caption` package

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum % Text before
\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
    \newgeometry{left=1cm, right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
    \thispagestyle{empty}% empty page style (?)
    \atxy{\dimexpr\paperwidth-1cm}{.5\paperheight}{\rotatebox[origin=center]{90}{\thepage}}
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
        \centering % Center table
        \begin{tabular}{llll}
            A & B & C & D \\
        \end{tabular}
        \captionof{table}{Table caption}% Add 'table' caption
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage% Flush page
    \aftergroup\restoregeometry
}
\lipsum % Text after
\end{document}
```

Comment: in your example, you used `geometry` to set the top and left margins to 35mm.  Thus, `\PageTopMargin` and `\PageLeftMargin` should likewise be set to 35mm.  Things that occur at shipout (like `\afterpage` and `\AddThispageHook`) are tricky.  in that some parameters from the prior page geometry are still active.  My guess is the `\newgeometry` settings didn't make their way into the `\atxy` formulation, though on a subsequent page, they might.