# Bold Rotated Page Numbers with landscape tables

Tags: page-numbering

As odd as it is, grad. schools want rotated page  numbers with landscape tables. I searched this site and many others. The one that worked for me is Leo Liu's from this site. Here it is (I have a long preamble, this is the end):

```
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing}
    \usepackage{longtable}

    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \fancypagestyle{lscapedplain}{%
      \fancyhf{}
       \fancyfoot{%
       \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[outer sep=1cm,above,rotate=90] at (current page.east) {\thepage};}
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  }

 \begin{document}

  \begin{landscape}
  \thispagestyle{lscapedplain}
  \pagestyle{lscapedplain}
  \begin{table}[htb!] 
   %%%
   \end{table}
   \end{landscape}
   \pagestyle{plain}
```

This gives me a rotated page with rotated page number. But my page number is bold, looks different from the others. Plus I want to be able to play with its placement if possible. I'd appreciate any and all answers. Than you.

Comment: Perhaps this will help, maybe even a duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258595/rotate-landscape-for-single-page-and-also-the-pagenumber

Comment: That is a beautiful solution. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I am not sure why, but it keeps giving an error with your code. As I said, I have many packages, probably there is a clash or something. Right now I have something that works. I was hoping to find a way to improve it.  Thanks so much.

Comment: It's not boldface, it's just been repeated three times  You should use \fancyfoot[C]{...} instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved in comments