# Page number of a page with landscape layout not visible

Tags: tables, koma-script, landscape

This question continues my [another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442382/page-numbers-are-still-too-deep-even-with-the-option-onpsinit-linespread1):

I found several suggestion here on TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209685/landscape-mode-and-page-numbering), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312936/bold-rotated-page-numbers-with-landscape-tables), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278113/single-landscape-page-with-page-number-at-the-bottom/278169)...). But I don't know which is more suitable for my case.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
               usegeometry = on,
               DIV = calc,
               french,
               english,
               ngerman
              ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[
            left = 25mm,
            bottom = 20mm,
            right = 45mm,
            top = 20mm,
            includehead,
            heightrounded
           ]{geometry}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{%
                                       \ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.foot}
                                       {
                                        \ModifyLayer[
                                                     voffset = \paperheight - 2\baselineskip,
                                                     align = b
                                                    ]{#1}
                                       }
                                       {}%
                                      }
\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
            showframe,
            babel,
            filecontents,
            csquotes,
            pdflscape,
            tabularx
           }
\usepackage[
            backend = biber,
            sortlocale = auto,
            sorting = nyt,
            style = ext-authoryear-comp
           ]{biblatex}

\newcommand*\english[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

  @MVREFERENCE{Janes,
               EDITOR    = {\english{Jane's}\textsuperscript{\textregistered}},
               LOCATION  = {\english{Coulsdon, Surrey} (GB)},
               PUBLISHER = {IHS Markit},
               DATE      = {2017},
               EDITION   = {2017--2018},
               SUBTITLE  = {\english{Development \& Production}},
               TITLE     = {\english{All the World's Aircraft}},
              }

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

  Text.
  \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
      \centering
      \caption{Übersicht über den Einsatz des Triebwerks PW1000G}
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cccXc}
        Hersteller                           & Flugzeugbezeichnung   & Entwicklungsland/Region & aktueller Entwicklungsstand                                   & Quelle\\
        \english{Airbus}                     & A319neo/320neo/321neo & Europa                  & Liniendienst, Stand 25.~Januar 2016                           & \autocite[338]{Janes}\\
        \foreignlanguage{french}{Bombardier} & \english{C-Series}    & Kanada                  & Liniendienst, Stand 31.~Dezember 2016                         & \autocite[101]{Janes}\\
        Mitsubishi                           & MRJ                   & Japan                   & erste Auslieferung Mitte 2020 geplannt, Stand 23.~Januar~2017 & \autocite[501]{Janes}\\
        Irkut                                & MS-21                 & Russische Föderation    & erste Auslieferung Ende 2018 geplant, Stand 8.~Juni 2016      & \autocite[567]{Janes}
      \end{tabularx}
      Quelle: Eigene Darstellung nach \autocite[101, 338, 501 und 567]{Janes}.
    \end{table}
  \end{landscape}
  Text.

\end{document}
```

The result (page one):
[image: page 1]
and (page two):
[image: page 2]
Why is it so? What is to do? I'am open for any suggestion. For example to redesign the layout or to optimize the table in such way that I can skip the landscape layout for the page with the table.

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Comment: You could try `sidewaysable` from the `rotating` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hack to reposition the footer is causing this behavior. If you use the default (and recommended) way to position the footer:

```
\setlength{\footskip}{13mm}
```

you can achieve the desired positioning and everything keeps working as intended:

```
\documentclass[
usegeometry = on,
DIV = calc,
french,
english,
ngerman
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[
left = 25mm,
bottom = 20mm,
right = 45mm,
top = 20mm,
includehead,
heightrounded,
showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{%
%  \ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.foot}
%  {
%    \ModifyLayer[
%    voffset = \paperheight - 2\baselineskip,
%    align = b
%    ]{#1}
%  }
%  {}%
%}
\setlength{\footskip}{13mm}

\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
%  showframe,
  babel,
  filecontents,
  csquotes,
  pdflscape,
  tabularx
}
\usepackage[
backend = biber,
sortlocale = auto,
sorting = nyt,
style = ext-authoryear-comp
]{biblatex}

\newcommand*\english[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

  @MVREFERENCE{Janes,
    EDITOR    = {\english{Jane's}\textsuperscript{\textregistered}},
    LOCATION  = {\english{Coulsdon, Surrey} (GB)},
    PUBLISHER = {IHS Markit},
    DATE      = {2017},
    EDITION   = {2017--2018},
    SUBTITLE  = {\english{Development \& Production}},
    TITLE     = {\english{All the World's Aircraft}},
  }

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Übersicht über den Einsatz des Triebwerks PW1000G}
    \begin{tabular}{rp{20mm}p{32mm}C{35mm}C{25mm}}
      Hersteller                           & \parbox[b]{\linewidth}{Flugzeug\-bezeichnung}   & \parbox[b]{\linewidth}{Entwicklungs\-land/ Region} & \parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\centering aktueller \mbox{Entwicklungsstand} (Datum)}                                   & \parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\centering Quelle\newline\mbox{\autocite{Janes}}}\\
      \hline
      \english{Airbus}\rule{0pt}{13pt}                     & A319neo/ A320neo/ A321neo & Europa                  & Liniendienst \mbox{(25.~Januar 2016)}                           & S. 338\\
      \foreignlanguage{french}{Bombardier} & \english{C-Series}    & Kanada                  & Liniendienst \mbox{(31.~Dezember 2016)}                         & S. 101\\
      Mitsubishi                           & MRJ                   & Japan                   & erste Auslieferung Mitte 2020 geplannt \mbox{(23.~Januar~2017)} & S. 501\\
      Irkut                                & MS-21                 & Russische \mbox{Föderation}    & erste Auslieferung Ende 2018 geplant \mbox{(8.~Juni 2016)}      & S. 567\\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \rule{0pt}{13pt}Quelle: Eigene Darstellung nach \autocite[101, 338, 501 und 567]{Janes}.
  \end{table}


  \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
      \centering
      \caption{Übersicht über den Einsatz des Triebwerks PW1000G}
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cccXc}
        Hersteller                           & Flugzeugbezeichnung   & Entwicklungsland/Region & aktueller Entwicklungsstand                                   & Quelle\\
        \english{Airbus}                     & A319neo/320neo/321neo & Europa                  & Liniendienst, Stand 25.~Januar 2016                           & \autocite[338]{Janes}\\
        \foreignlanguage{french}{Bombardier} & \english{C-Series}    & Kanada                  & Liniendienst, Stand 31.~Dezember 2016                         & \autocite[101]{Janes}\\
        Mitsubishi                           & MRJ                   & Japan                   & erste Auslieferung Mitte 2020 geplannt, Stand 23.~Januar~2017 & \autocite[501]{Janes}\\
        Irkut                                & MS-21                 & Russische Föderation    & erste Auslieferung Ende 2018 geplant, Stand 8.~Juni 2016      & \autocite[567]{Janes}
      \end{tabularx}
      Quelle: Eigene Darstellung nach \autocite[101, 338, 501 und 567]{Janes}.
    \end{table}
  \end{landscape}
  Text.

\end{document}
```

I used the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package instead of loading the `showframe` package.

**edit:** I made a more compact version of this table, see updated code above and image:

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

Load package `scrhack`:

```
\documentclass[
               usegeometry = on,
               DIV = calc,
               french,
               english,
               ngerman
              ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrhack}% <- added

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[
            left = 25mm,
            bottom = 20mm,
            right = 45mm,
            top = 20mm,
            includehead,
            heightrounded
           ]{geometry}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{%
                                       \ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.foot}
                                       {
                                        \ModifyLayer[
                                                     voffset = \paperheight - 2\baselineskip,
                                                     align = b
                                                    ]{#1}
                                       }
                                       {}%
                                      }
\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
            showframe,
            babel,
            filecontents,
            csquotes,
            pdflscape,
            tabularx
           }
\usepackage[
            backend = biber,
            sortlocale = auto,
            sorting = nyt,
            style = ext-authoryear-comp
           ]{biblatex}

\newcommand*\english[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{#1}}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

  @MVREFERENCE{Janes,
               EDITOR    = {\english{Jane's}\textsuperscript{\textregistered}},
               LOCATION  = {\english{Coulsdon, Surrey} (GB)},
               PUBLISHER = {IHS Markit},
               DATE      = {2017},
               EDITION   = {2017--2018},
               SUBTITLE  = {\english{Development \& Production}},
               TITLE     = {\english{All the World's Aircraft}},
              }

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

  Text.
  \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
      \centering
      \caption{Übersicht über den Einsatz des Triebwerks PW1000G}
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cccXc}
        Hersteller                           & Flugzeugbezeichnung   & Entwicklungsland/Region & aktueller Entwicklungsstand                                   & Quelle\\
        \english{Airbus}                     & A319neo/320neo/321neo & Europa                  & Liniendienst, Stand 25.~Januar 2016                           & \autocite[338]{Janes}\\
        \foreignlanguage{french}{Bombardier} & \english{C-Series}    & Kanada                  & Liniendienst, Stand 31.~Dezember 2016                         & \autocite[101]{Janes}\\
        Mitsubishi                           & MRJ                   & Japan                   & erste Auslieferung Mitte 2020 geplannt, Stand 23.~Januar~2017 & \autocite[501]{Janes}\\
        Irkut                                & MS-21                 & Russische Föderation    & erste Auslieferung Ende 2018 geplant, Stand 8.~Juni 2016      & \autocite[567]{Janes}
      \end{tabularx}
      Quelle: Eigene Darstellung nach \autocite[101, 338, 501 und 567]{Janes}.
    \end{table}
  \end{landscape}
  Text.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

For more information see documentation of package `scrhack` in the KOMA-Script documentation (scrguien.pdf), especially section "16.6. Inconsistent Handling of \textwidth and \textheight".