# How to enlarge the print area of the title page?

Tags: koma-script, geometry

This question is a follow-up of my [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442620/page-number-of-a-page-with-landscape-layout-not-visible)

My title page have too much information and didn't fit on one page:

```
\documentclass[
               usegeometry = on,
               DIV = calc,
               titlepage,
               ngerman
              ]{scrartcl}
% layout
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[
            pass,
            showframe
           ]{geometry}
\usepackage[
            singlespacing,
            headsepline
           ]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.75\baselineskip}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chead{\headmark}
\automark{section}
\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}
% other packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
            lmodern,
            babel,
            graphicx
           }
% signatures
\newlength\ruleLengthForSignatures\settowidth
\ruleLengthForSignatures{Author with the longest name}
\newcommand*\Rule{\rule{\ruleLengthForSignatures}{.4pt}}
% title page, from https://komascript.de/comment/770#comment-770
\titlehead{
           \begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}
             Technische Universität Berlin\\
             Institut für Land- und Seeverkehr, Verkehrswesenseminar\\
             Straße X--X\\
             12345 Berlin\\
             Sommersemester X\\
             Einführung in das Verkehrswesen\\
             Tutorium X\\
             Gruppe X
           \end{minipage}
           \hfill
           \begin{minipage}{.25\linewidth}
             \begin{flushright}
               \vspace{-32mm}
               \includegraphics[scale=.25]{TU}
             \end{flushright}
           \end{minipage}
           \centerline{\hrulefill}
          }
\subject{Wissenschaftliche Ausarbeitung}
\title{
       Alternative Antriebe in der Luftfahrt\\
       \vspace{5mm}
       \includegraphics[scale=.2]{Verkehrswesenseminar}
      }
\subtitle{Inwiefern müssen zivile Zweistrom- und Propeller-Turbinen-Luftstrahltriebwerke bis zum Jahr 2050 unter Berücksichtigung der Rahmenbedingungen zur Reduzierung der Schadstoffemissionen konstruktiv weiterentwickelt und durch brennstoffliche Alternativen verbessert oder durch triebwerkliche Innovationen ersetzt werden?}
\author{Author One\\\small{123456}\and Author Two\\\small{123456}\and Author Three\\\small{123456}}
\date{Abgabetermin: \today\\Vorgelegt am: \today}
\publishers{Betreut durch Tutor}

\begin{document}

  \begin{spacing}{1}
    \maketitle
  \end{spacing}
  \newgeometry{
               left = 25mm,
               bottom = 20mm,
               right = 45mm,
               top = 20mm,
               includehead,
               heightrounded
              }

  \section{Test}
    Text.

\end{document}
```

The links to the pictures in the code: [TU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFQD3.png) and [Verkehrswesenseminar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A6dT.png).

How can I fit my title page within one page? Any solution is welcome, but the information for the title page can't be cut and only the big picture can be scaled slightly.

Comment: As always, it is easiest to create the title page as a standalone document and just to include the pdf.

Comment: You should also have a look at https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes no sense to use the `typearea` setting with `DIV` *and* `geometry`.
Use *only*. `geometry`. However, it makes sense to use the environment `titlepage` instead of `\maketitle`.

```
\documentclass[
titlepage,
ngerman,
usegeometry
]{scrartcl}
% layout
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[
  pass,
  showframe,
  left = 25mm,
  bottom = 20mm,
  right = 45mm,
  top = 20mm,
  includehead,
  heightrounded
]{geometry}
\usepackage[
singlespacing,
headsepline
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.75\baselineskip}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chead{\headmark}
\automark{section}
\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}
% other packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
    lmodern,
    babel,
    graphicx
}
% signatures
\newlength\ruleLengthForSignatures\settowidth
\ruleLengthForSignatures{Author with the longest name}
\newcommand*\Rule{\rule{\ruleLengthForSignatures}{.4pt}}
% title page, from https://komascript.de/comment/770#comment-770
\titlehead{
    \begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}
        Technische Universität Berlin\\
        Institut für Land- und Seeverkehr, Verkehrswesenseminar\\
        Straße X--X\\
        12345 Berlin\\
        Sommersemester X\\
        Einführung in das Verkehrswesen\\
        Tutorium X\\
        Gruppe X
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.25\linewidth}
        \begin{flushright}
            \vspace{-32mm}
            \includegraphics[scale=.25]{../../../private/tmp/VFQD3}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}
    \centerline{\hrulefill}
}
\subject{Wissenschaftliche Ausarbeitung}
\title{
    Alternative Antriebe in der Luftfahrt\\
    \vspace{5mm}
    \includegraphics[scale=.2]{../../../private/tmp/3A6dT}
}
\subtitle{Inwiefern müssen zivile Zweistrom- und Propeller-Turbinen-Luftstrahltriebwerke bis zum Jahr 2050 unter Berücksichtigung der Rahmenbedingungen zur Reduzierung der Schadstoffemissionen konstruktiv weiterentwickelt und durch brennstoffliche Alternativen verbessert oder durch triebwerkliche Innovationen ersetzt werden?}
\author{Author One\\\small{123456}\and Author Two\\\small{123456}\and Author Three\\\small{123456}}
\date{Abgabetermin: \today\\Vorgelegt am: \today}
\publishers{Betreut durch Tutor}

\begin{document}

    \newgeometry{margin=1cm}
    \begin{spacing}{1}
        \maketitle
    \end{spacing}
\clearpage

\restoregeometry

    \section{Test}
    Text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @Herbert! Thank you for your answer! Could you please provide an example with the environment `titlepage`? Maybe you can edit your answer and built the example in? It's very interesting for me! One question: In your answer for the option `usegeometry` I missing this part: `=on`. Is there an implicit mechanism, which enables the options by using their names?

Comment: see http://latex.userpage.fu-berlin.de/Materialien/VOrlageFUmitTitel.zip

Comment: Hello @Herbert! Sorry for the long delay! Thank you for your comment and the link! Two things: I didn't found the `hyperref` option `linktoc=all` in the option [summary](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/options.pdf) and the `scrreprt` option `openany=false` in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf). Could you please explain this options or provide an information source? Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Answer (score 2):

KOMA-Script classes provide the possibility of a different layout for the first title page. Add the value `firstiscover` to option `titlepage`. Then you can redefine `\coverpagetopmargin`, `\coverpagebottommargin`, `\coverpageleftmargin` and `\coverpagerightmargin` to your needs.

```
\documentclass[
               usegeometry = on,
               DIV = calc,
               titlepage=firstiscover,% <- changed
               ngerman
              ]{scrartcl}
% layout
\renewcommand{\coverpagetopmargin}{1cm}% <- added
\renewcommand{\coverpagebottommargin}{1cm}% <- added
\renewcommand{\coverpageleftmargin}{1cm}% <- added
\renewcommand{\coverpagerightmargin}{1cm}% <- added
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[
            showframe,
            left = 25mm,
            bottom = 20mm,
            right = 45mm,
            top = 20mm,
            includehead,
            heightrounded
           ]{geometry}
\usepackage[
            singlespacing,
            headsepline
           ]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.75\baselineskip}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chead{\headmark}
\automark{section}
\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}
% other packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{
            lmodern,
            babel,
            graphicx
           }
% signatures
\newlength\ruleLengthForSignatures\settowidth
\ruleLengthForSignatures{Author with the longest name}
\newcommand*\Rule{\rule{\ruleLengthForSignatures}{.4pt}}
% title page, from https://komascript.de/comment/770#comment-770
\titlehead{
           \begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}
             Technische Universität Berlin\\
             Institut für Land- und Seeverkehr, Verkehrswesenseminar\\
             Straße X--X\\
             12345 Berlin\\
             Sommersemester X\\
             Einführung in das Verkehrswesen\\
             Tutorium X\\
             Gruppe X
           \end{minipage}
           \hfill
           \begin{minipage}{.25\linewidth}
             \begin{flushright}
               \vspace{-32mm}
               \includegraphics[scale=.25]{TU}
             \end{flushright}
           \end{minipage}
           \centerline{\hrulefill}
          }
\subject{Wissenschaftliche Ausarbeitung}
\title{
       Alternative Antriebe in der Luftfahrt\\
       \vspace{5mm}
       \includegraphics[scale=.2]{Verkehrswesenseminar}
      }
\subtitle{Inwiefern müssen zivile Zweistrom- und Propeller-Turbinen-Luftstrahltriebwerke bis zum Jahr 2050 unter Berücksichtigung der Rahmenbedingungen zur Reduzierung der Schadstoffemissionen konstruktiv weiterentwickelt und durch brennstoffliche Alternativen verbessert oder durch triebwerkliche Innovationen ersetzt werden?}
\author{Author One\\\small{123456}\and Author Two\\\small{123456}\and Author Three\\\small{123456}}
\date{Abgabetermin: \today\\Vorgelegt am: \today}
\publishers{Betreut durch Tutor}

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1}
  \maketitle
\end{spacing}

\section{Test}
Text.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the redefinition of `\coverpagetopmargin` etc would also work if package `geometry` was not loaded. In the example it is only used for the other pages.