# Landscape longtable pagenumber rotation works only for 1 page!

Tags: tables, longtable, rotating, landscape, everypage

Assume I want to draw a multi-page landscape table. Also I want to rotate the pagenumber to landscape. I figured out the following MWE for this, however as you can see, **it rotates only the pagenumber for the first page.**

Edit: Typo: In the screenshot the pagenumber of page 2 is of course portrait again, and not landscape.

So my questions are:

- **How to disable pagestyle for all pages the longtable in running?**  The '\thispagestyle'  only works for 'this' page -).
- How to get \AddThispageHook running for all longtable pages? **I can switch to everypage \AddEverypageHook, but how to disable this afterwards?**

*Credits: Page number rotation /atxy : Steven Segletes in the [TeX stackexchange post here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258595/rotate-landscape-for-single-page-and-also-the-pagenumber).  Long table example: Overleaf website.*

[image]
[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\def\PageLeftMargin{3cm}
\def\PageBottomMargin{1in}
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddThispageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{#3}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \atxy{\the\dimexpr\paperwidth-1cm}{.5\paperheight}{\rotatebox[origin=center]{90}{\thepage}}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot
\hline \hline
\endlastfoot
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ 
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to change \thiskpagestyle to \pagestyle.  It will revert automatically at the end of the environment.  Changing \AddThispageHook to \AddEverypageHook is slightly trickier.

Comment: BTW, the default margins waste a lot of space, especially in landscape.

Answer (score 2):

This will add the page number to the right of every landscape page in the entire document.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{everypage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\AddEverypageHook{\ifdim\textwidth=\textheight
  \raisebox{\dimexpr 1in-0.5\paperheight}[0pt][0pt]%
    {\rlap{\hspace*{\dimexpr \paperwidth-1in-1cm}% place page number 1 cm from page edge
    \rotatebox[origin=center]{90}{\thepage}}}
\fi}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \hline 
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot
\hline \hline
\endlastfoot
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ 
\end{longtable}
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{\textheight}% available space
\end{landscape}
normal page
\end{document}
```