# Floatrow package conflicting with centering longtable

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, longtable, floatrow

Consider the MWE below. If I `\usepackage{floatrow}` the `longtable` is not horizontal centered. If I comment out `\usepackage{floatrow}` the table is properly horizontal centered.

**How can I get this snippet working** (both use `floatrow` and center the `longtable`)?

**Credits:** Landscape construction (stripped down by me for MWE): [Steven B. Segletes in this answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258598/74646)

**Without usepackage floatrow in below MWE (correct):**

[image]

**With usepackage  floatrow in below MWE (not centered anymore):**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
% >> 'PROBLEM' package
\usepackage{floatrow}
% << 'PROBLEM' package
\begin{document}
Document is portrait
\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% Flush earlier floats (otherwise order might not be correct)
        \newgeometry{left=1cm, right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
        \pagestyle{empty}
        \centering % Center table
        \vspace{0pt}
        \begin{singlespacing}
\begin{longtable}{rr}
 \caption{Table is landscape.}
 \tabularnewline
 \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2}\tabularnewline
 \midrule
 \endfirsthead
 \caption{Caption (Continued)}\tabularnewline
 \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2}\tabularnewline
\midrule
 \endhead
 \bottomrule
 \multicolumn{2}{r}{Cont}
 \endfoot
 \bottomrule
 \endlastfoot
 A & B \tabularnewline
 C & D \tabularnewline
\end{longtable}
    \end{singlespacing}
    \end{landscape}
    \clearpage% Flush page
}
\restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\centering` never has any affect on longtable.

Comment: Well, if you run MWE with usepackage{floatrow} commented out, you will see that it works. So if you say that it is not work, can you clarify why it nevertheless works? E.g. is it by default centering?

Comment: longtables are centred by default unless you use `[l]` or `[r]` but `\centering`, `\flushright` don't do anything as they are always full width.

Comment: So then the question is: why is this default behavior broken after importing floatrow, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some strange reason `floatrow` sets `\LTleft` and `\LTright` to 0pt breaking longtable's default positioning, you could set them back, or simpler just use

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{rr}
```

to force longtable to centre.

---

this is sort of mentioned in the `floatrow` manual

> Alignment Settings for longtable. The floatrow expands some settings
>   of table lay- out to the longtable environment, so you may set \LTleft
>   and \LTright parameters inside \DeclareMarginSet settings. For
>   example, centering option was defined like:
>       `\DeclareMarginSet{centering}{\setfloatmargins{\hfill}{\hfill}%
>         \LTleft=\fill \LTright=\fill}`

Answer (score 1):

this may be the solution:

```
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{floatrow}
 - \floatsetup[longtable]{margins=centering}
```

### UPDATE

Package "float" is used with kable and kableExtra.

When we need to place the caption of a figure at the top the only solution I have found is to use the "floatrow" package.

Since "float" and "floatrow" are incompatible, it is necessary to add some additional configurations in "floatrow" so that the appearance of the tables generated with kable and kableExtra using rstudio, rmarkdown and knitr is identical.

```
header-includes:
 - \usepackage{floatrow}
 - \floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top} % Caption figure top.
 - \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top} % Caption table top.
 - \floatplacement{figure}{H} % Figure position according to the code flow.
 - \floatplacement{table}{H} % Table position according to the code flow.
 - \floatsetup[longtable]{margins=centering} % Longtable tables centered.
```

Comment: What do you mean with "may be"? have you tried it? Result?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it.