# longtable captionsetup name option

Tags: tables, captions, longtable

I found a issue when you try to change the table caption `name` option, while using a `longtable`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

%CAPTION
\usepackage{caption}

%TABELLENÜBERSCHRIFT FORMATIERUNG
\captionsetup[table]{name=Tab.,labelfont=bf, font=footnotesize, justification=RaggedRight, singlelinecheck=false, format=plain, textformat=period}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

%TABLE
\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\ttabbox{\caption{Abc}}{\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}A & B & C & D \\A & B & C & D\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

%LONG TABLE
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c}
A & B & A & B \\ \hline 
A & B & A & B \\ \hline
A & B & A & B \\ \hline
A & B & A & B \\ \hline
\caption{Abc}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

`pdflatex.exe` returns:

> ! Undefined control
>   sequence. (longtable)

after removing `name=Tab.` from `\captionsetup` everything works fine.

How can I solve that issue, and how can I format the longtable caption like table caption (caption over table)?

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.6960 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.3.4) 5 MAR 2019 09:33
```

Comment: Seems `floatrow` and `longtable` can not live together ...

Comment: Did you saw related question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320592/floatrow-package-conflicting-with-centering-longtable ?

Comment: You can compile also after deleting `floatrow` and command `\ttabbox`.  Do you really need `floatrow`?

Comment: For me, the problem seems to come from `caption: when I delete it, it compiles fine.

Comment: It seems to be an incompatibility between `caption` and `floatrow` regarding the `longtable` environment which is patched by both. So the problem comes from neither one or the other package, it's the combination which causes a problem here. Solution: Don't use `name=Tab.` and load the `caption` package with `\usepackage[tablename=Tab.]{caption}` instead. In the meantime I will try to eliminate the incompatibility, please hold the line...

Comment: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the longtable code of the `floatrow` package (inside the re-definition of `\LT@array`). It sets the caption options for `table` and `longtable` without defining `\@captype` to `table` first.

This bug is only relevant if the combination `floatrow`, `longtable`, `caption`, `\captionsetup{...}` is used and if the caption options used needs `\@captype` to be defined (like the option `name=...`).

Work-around: Don't use `\captionsetup[table]{name=...}` but `\usepackage[tablename=...]{caption}` instead.

Since the `floatrow` package is unmaintained (so nobody will fix it) I included a patch of the faulty `floatrow` code to the `caption` package v3.4g, so the work-around is no longer needed when using this version (or newer) of the `caption` package.