# Incorrect Width Using xltabular and floatrow Together

Tags: tables, floatrow, xltabular

`floatrow` settings seem to break `xltabular` but only in certain cases. If all columns have `X`, it will work with no problem. Also note that `tabularx` is not impacted.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\floatsetup[table]{font = small, capposition = top}

\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|ccX|}
    \caption{Not correct.} \\
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|ccX|}
    \caption{Not correct either.} \\
    \toprule
    1 longer text & 2 emmm & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|XXX|}
    \caption{But this works.} \\
    \toprule
    1 longer text & 2 emmm & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}

\null

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{No problem for \texttt{tabularx}.}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|ccX|}
    \toprule
    1 longer text & 2 emmm & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution after I look into the `.sty` source files.

`floatrow` and `xltabular` all have some definitions about `\LTxxx`, so loading `floatrow` before `xltabular` can solve the width issue. Some related discussions about `floatrow` and `longtable` is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/320592/234654).

The side effect is that the font setting in `\floatsetup` does not apply now. As a workaround, we can `\renewenvironment` the `xltabular` to hard code the font size into it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{xltabular}[1][x]%
{%
  \small % <-- font size change
  \par
  \if l#1%
    \LTleft\z@ \LTright\fill
  \else\if r#1%
    \LTleft\fill \LTright\z@
  \else\if c#1%
    \LTleft\fill \LTright\fill
  \fi\fi\fi
  \let\TX@endtabularx=\XLT@ii@TX@endtabularx
  \let\endtabularx\endxltabular
  \XLT@ii@tabularx}
{\def\@currenvir{tabularx}}
\makeatletter

\floatsetup[table]{font = small, capposition = top}

\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|ccX|}
    \caption{Not correct.} \\
    \toprule
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|ccX|}
    \caption{Not correct either.} \\
    \toprule
    1 longer text & 2 emmm & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|XXX|}
    \caption{But this works.} \\
    \toprule
    1 longer text & 2 emmm & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}

\null

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{No problem for \texttt{tabularx}.}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|ccX|}
    \toprule
    1 longer text & 2 emmm & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

ALL is working now.

\end{document}
```

[image: Correct Result]