# Problem with interesting recipe format

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, fun, intersections

I was wandering through the internet and came across http://graphicalcooking.co. An attractive format, and I said to myself, "TikZ can do that!" And so it can. I wrestled with this this morning and have arrived at the following. My only problem is the lines connecting the hexagons in the instructions for the recipe. I cannot think of a way to get the various lines to intersect with each other (at the circled locations) without explicitly computing the distances. It would be nice to have a macro, `\connect` that would do the work, say, by use of the `intersections` TikZ library. Any suggestions? I hope I have commented the code sufficiently that there are no mysteries... I've included a couple of examples of what the as-yet fictional `\connect` macro might do.

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Compare with http://graphicalcooking.co

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.5in,bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.geometric,intersections}

\newlength{\minsize}
\newlength{\skipln}

\setlength{\minsize}{1.00in}
\setlength{\skipln}{0.1in}

\def\fr#1/#2 {\sfrac{#1}{#2} }

\tikzset{% Simplify using TikZ pics
    pics/hex/.style n args={4}{% #1= name; #2=color; #3 top in bold; #4 bottom in italics
        code={%
            \node[%
                draw,
                very thick,
                color=#2,
                rounded corners=3pt,
                regular polygon, 
                regular polygon sides=6,
                shape border rotate=90, %% !!
                inner sep=0pt,
                minimum size=\minsize,
                inner sep=0pt,
                align=center
            ] (#1)  at (0,0) {};
            \node[text width=0.95\minsize,align=center]  at (#1)
                {\textbf{\strut#3\strut}\\\emph{\strut#4\strut}};
        }
    }
}

\tikzset{rc/.style = {rounded corners=3pt}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\movehex}{cos(30) * \minsize} %% (0,0) to *side* of hexagon
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\branchln}{(\movehex+\skipln)/2/cos(30)} %% length of line after bend

%%  Create the hexagons
\pic at (0,0) {hex={A}{blue}{Parmesan}{\fr1/4 cup}};
\pic at (\movehex+\skipln,0.0in) {hex={C}{green!70!black}{Lettuce}{\fr1/2 head}};
\pic at (2*\movehex+2*\skipln,0.0in) {hex={D}{orange}{Carrot}{1}};
\pic at (0.5*\movehex+\skipln/2,-\movehex+\skipln/2) {hex={B}{red}{Tomato}{1}};
\pic at (1.5*\movehex+3*\skipln/2,-\movehex+\skipln/2) {hex={E}{purple}{Red Onion}{\fr1/4 }};
\pic at ($(E) + (\movehex+\skipln,0)$) {hex={F}{yellow!80!green}{EVOO}{\fr1/4 cup}};
\pic at ($(F) + (\movehex+\skipln,0)$) {hex={G}{pink}{Red Wine\\Vinegar}{\fr1/8 cup}};

\coordinate (t1) at ($(B)!.5!(E)$);

\path (t1) -- ++(0,-3.5in) coordinate (t2);

%% Draw the connections
%% This would be neater with a macro something like (\connect yet to be defined!):
%% \connect{1.75in}{B.south}{C.south}{0.85in}{Place in bowl} where
%% #1=vertical displacement; #2=source coordinate; #3=coordinate with which to align end of connector
%% #4=vertical displacement for instruction; #5=instruction
%% Would also allow for arbitrary placement of hexagons
\draw[thick] (C.south) -- (t2);
\draw[rc,blue] (B.south) -- ++(0,-1.75in) -- ++(-30:\branchln) node[circle,draw] {};
%% or \connect{-1.75in}{B.south}{C.south}{0.85in}{Place in bowl}
\draw[rc] (E.south) -- ++(0,-1.5in) -- ++(210:\branchln) node[circle,draw] {};
\draw[rc,red] (A.south) -- ++(0,-1.75in) -- ++(-30:\branchln) node[circle,draw] {};
%% or \connect{-1.5in}{A.south}{B.south}{0.5in}{Slice}
\draw[rc] (D.south) -- ++(0,-2.5in) -- ++(210:2*\branchln) node[circle,draw] {};
\draw[rc] (F.south) -- ++(0,-0.25in) -- ++(-30:\branchln) node[circle,draw] {};
\draw[rc] (G.south) -- ++(0,-0.25in) -- ++(210:\branchln) coordinate (i1);
\draw[rc] (i1) -- ++(0,-1in) -- ++(210:4*\branchln) node[circle,draw] {};

%% Ingredient instructions
\node[below=0.85in of C.south,fill=white] {Place in bowl};
\node[below=1.0in of A.south,fill=white] {Grate};
\node[below=0.5in of B.south,fill=white] {Slice};
\node[below=1.0in of E.south,fill=white] {Dice};
\node[below=1.25in of D.south,fill=white] {Chop};
\node[below=0.25in of i1,fill=white] {Mix in blender};
\node[draw,fill=white,rounded corners=3pt] at (t2) {\strut Toss \& Serve};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\skipln}{0.025in}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\movehex}{cos(30) * \minsize}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\branchln}{(\movehex+\skipln)/2/cos(30)}
\pic at (0,-5.25in) {hex={P}{blue}{Parmesan}{}};
\pic at ($(P) + (-60:\movehex+\skipln)$) {hex={Q}{green!70!black}{blue/Z2}{}};
\pic at ($(P) + (\movehex+\skipln,0)$) {hex={R}{orange}{Cheddar\\xxx}{}};
\pic at ($(R) + (\movehex+\skipln,0)$) {hex={S}{purple}{Eggplant\\yyy}{}};
\pic at ($(Q) + (\movehex+\skipln,0)$) {hex={T}{yellow}{Cream\\zzz}{}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OT: EVOO = Extra Virgin Olive Oil I guess...  is that a common initialism?

Comment: Yes, it is quite common in foodie literature.

Comment: Oh  god. Such a receipe would drive me mad ;-)

Comment: It is not considered, even, I think, by the originators, as any more than an *aide-mémoire* for very simple recipes, as it lacks substantive instructions. Moreover, complex recipes (cassoulet or boeuf bourguignon) could not be credibly represented in this way. Also, my example is a very rough first-approximation. Still, I can see your point...

Comment: Chopped carrot... wouldn't grated be easier to eat?  And sliced tomato is not very specific; disks or wedges?

Comment: @HenriMenke -- As I said this is a very crude first approximation. And, yes, grated would make more sense. If I get a reply to my question, I'll update accordingly.

Comment: This is kind of a tree growing upwards, so the problem is actually making the hexagons appear alternating. I guess forest would be able to do that though I have no idea about it.

Comment: @percusse Looks like a tree to me, too. I took a look at the forest option, but there were just too many imponderables. I was impatient to get *something* even as just a starting point.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a proposal. I think to have more or less implemented your command except that I replaced the second absolute distance by the fraction of the path. I also like the fact that there is no pineapple in the recipe.

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Compare with http://graphicalcooking.co
\makeatletter % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412901/121799
\newcommand{\Distance}[3]{% % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56353/121799
\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone($#1-#2$)\relax  
\pgfmathsetmacro{#3}{veclen(\the\pgf@x,\the\pgf@y)/28.45274}
}
\makeatother 
\newcommand{\Connect}[6][]{%
\node[above=#2 of #4,circle,draw,#1] (y){};
\coordinate (x) at (y-|#3);
\Distance{(x)}{(y)}{\myDst}%\typeout{\myDst}
\ifthenelse {\isempty{#6}}{\draw[rc,#1] (#3) -- ($(x)+(0,0.6*\myDst)$)--(y.center);}{%
\draw[rc,#1] (#3) -- ($(x)+(0,0.6*\myDst)$)  node[pos=#5,fill=white]{#6}-- (y.center);}
}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.5in,bottom=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.geometric,intersections,calc}

\newlength{\minsize}
\newlength{\skipln}

\setlength{\minsize}{1.00in}
\setlength{\skipln}{0.1in}

\def\fr#1/#2 {\sfrac{#1}{#2} }

\tikzset{% Simplify using TikZ pics
    pics/hex/.style n args={4}{% #1= name; #2=color; #3 top in bold; #4 bottom in italics
        code={%
            \node[%
                draw,
                very thick,
                color=#2,
                rounded corners=3pt,
                regular polygon, 
                regular polygon sides=6,
                shape border rotate=90, %% !!
                inner sep=0pt,
                minimum size=\minsize,
                inner sep=0pt,
                align=center
            ] (#1)  at (0,0) {};
            \node[text width=0.95\minsize,align=center]  at (#1)
                {\textbf{\strut#3\strut}\\\emph{\strut#4\strut}};
        }
    }
}

\tikzset{rc/.style = {rounded corners=3pt}}



\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

%% \connect{1.75in}{B.south}{C.south}{0.85in}{Place in bowl} where
%% #1=vertical displacement; #2=source coordinate; #3=coordinate with which to align end of connector
%% #4=vertical displacement for instruction; #5=instruction
%% Would also allow for arbitrary placement of hexagons

\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\movehex}{cos(30) * \minsize} %% (0,0) to *side* of hexagon
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\branchln}{(\movehex+\skipln)/2/cos(30)} %% length of line after bend

%%  Create the hexagons
\pic at (0,0) {hex={A}{blue}{Parmesan}{\fr1/4 cup}};
\pic at (\movehex+\skipln,0.0in) {hex={C}{green!70!black}{Lettuce}{\fr1/2 head}};
\pic at (2*\movehex+2*\skipln,0.0in) {hex={D}{orange}{Carrot}{1}};
\pic at (0.5*\movehex+\skipln/2,-\movehex+\skipln/2) {hex={B}{red}{Tomato}{1}};
\pic at (1.5*\movehex+3*\skipln/2,-\movehex+\skipln/2) {hex={E}{purple}{Red Onion}{\fr1/4 }};
\pic at ($(E) + (\movehex+\skipln,0)$) {hex={F}{yellow!80!green}{EVOO}{\fr1/4 cup}};
\pic at ($(F) + (\movehex+\skipln,0)$) {hex={G}{pink}{Red Wine\\Vinegar}{\fr1/8 cup}};

\coordinate (t1) at ($(B)!.5!(E)$);

\path (t1) -- ++(0,-3.5in) coordinate (t2);

\draw[thick] (C.south) -- (t2) node[pos=0.3,fill=white]{Place in bowl};
\node[draw,fill=white,rounded corners=3pt] at (t2) {\strut Toss \& Serve};
\Connect[green]{1.75in}{E.south}{t2.north}{0.7}{Dice} 
\Connect[red]{0.75in}{B.south}{t2.north}{0.3}{Slice} 
\Connect[blue]{0.5in}{A.south}{x}{0.7}{Grate} 
% explanation: the `\Connect` command defines two nodes, x and y,
% which always get overwritten. I am using the x node from the previous
X \Connect here
\Connect[orange]{1.25in}{D.south}{t2.north}{0.7}{Chop}
\coordinate(dummy) at ($(F.south)!0.5!(G.south)+(0,-1in)$);
\Connect{0}{F.south}{dummy}{0.7}{}
\Connect{0}{G.south}{dummy}{0.7}{}
\Connect[thick]{0.25in}{dummy.south}{t2.north}{0.25}{Mix in blender}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The main problem, though, is that I really don't like onions. (That's why I connected them with the ugly color.) Could you please leave them out? (Garlic would be soooo much better and healthier!)

Comment: Very nice indeed! I do like pineapple, but not in this salad... Would crispy fried garlic be ok? ;)

Comment: Garlic? No way! Have you ever tried Tropea onions?

Comment: @sgmoye I also like pineapples, but not with tomatoes, especially since some freaks put pineapple on pizza. Can you believe it?

Comment: @marmot +1 for _I also like the fact that there is no pineapple in the recipe._